# How to toggle off Openlayers custom control?

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I've gone ahead and built a custom control that I'm adding to my map like so:

```
const BoundingBox = (function (Control) {
    function BoundingBox(optOptions) {
        const options = optOptions || {};

        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = '[]';

        const element = document.createElement('div');
        element.className = 'bounding-box ol-unselectable ol-control';
        element.appendChild(button);

        Control.call(this, {
            element,
            target: options.target,
        });

        button.addEventListener('click', this.handleBoundingBox.bind(this), false);
    }

    if (Control) BoundingBox.__proto__ = Control;
    BoundingBox.prototype = Object.create(Control && Control.prototype);
    BoundingBox.prototype.constructor = BoundingBox;

    BoundingBox.prototype.handleBoundingBox = function handleBoundingBox() {
        this.getMap().addInteraction(extent);
    };

    return BoundingBox;
}(Control));
```

Next, I added that control to my map when my map is initialized. This is working fine. Now, I'm trying to find a way to toggle off the BoundingBox control. I was thinking that I could use the .removeInteraction() method. However, I'm unsure if that's correct. Also, should that be applied in a separate function or in my BoundingBox control?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by checking the properties of the ol/interaction/extent and setting the value of the active property to false.

```
        extent.setProperties({ active: false });
```